# htaccess rule to consider double slashes as single

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project built using codeigniter. And the mistake I have made is that I have added "/" after the base_url() method in many links(href) I have given on the project files as shown below.

```
<? echo base_url();?>/about
```

So the URLS are looking like

```
http://myproject.com//about
```

in place of

```
http://myproject.com/about
```

And because of that, it is resulting to 404 error.

Now the situation is that the site is ready but I am only allowed to update the .htaccess file of the project to fix this.

So is there any rule I can write in .htaccess file so that it considers the double slashes in the URL as single slash and open the specific page?

Funny thing is, it was already considering double slashes as single slash somehow and opening the "About" page on the development server. But now as the server is changed, I have started facing the 404 issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to remove multiple `//`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked nicely. What if I want to achieve same in POST request? As I have also used base_url() in form action value.

Comment: Post data will be lost after a full URL redirect.

Answer (score 0):

actually you have set the base url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myproject.com/';
```

and when u are using it like this

```
<? echo base_url();?>/about
```

it is adding to // so you have to change your page like this

```
 <? echo base_url();?>about
```

and if you cant change your path then you can set your htaccess as

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```